# How can I load JavaScript files in back-end side for plugins TO footer instead of header

Tags: octobercms, octobercms-plugins

I need to add some on my JS script on footer instead of header since I want to use some things after DOM loaded.
I've already used the core function `addJs('script url')` there is no parameter to choose where to include JS scripts.

Comment: please mention that you need to add this js in back-end side for plugins , other wise user thinks that you need to add it in front-end.

Answer (score 1):

October Cms Backend shipped with `jQuery v2.1.3`already, so you can utilize `document ready` event for your `java-script code`.

back-end templates location is `modules\backend\layouts`  and `_head` is having `<?= $this->makeAssets() ?>` so all assets will be inserted here and its not good to change here.

just use

```
$this->addJs('/plugins/acme/blog/assets/javascript/some-code.js');
```

now inside your js file `(some-code.js)` wrap all of your code inside `document ready`method

```
$(document).ready(function(event) {
  // this code will execute only after DOM is loaded.
  console.log('dom is loaded !')

  // your code..


});
```

> now, its not matter where your code is `header` or `footer`, your code is always execute after `DOM is loaded`.

if you have any further problem then this one, just share your problem with proper details we can help you to solve it

Comment: i plane use Vuejs witch i need to call script at the end of page,because i have this warning Cannot find element: #myApp

Comment: hmm, where are you adding this `#myApp` and how you add this can you show us

Comment: i have a controller named "Position" with an empty function index(),i've created a file view named position/index.html ; here's the content of file  `<div id="myApp">
    <v-app>
      <v-content>
        <v-container>Hello world</v-container><br/>
      </v-content>
    </v-app>
  </div>` <br/> i've had a file custom.js wicth i use to instance a VueJs Object  here it is the content new `Vue({ el: '#myApp' })`

Comment: i manage to fix this error by adding `window.onload = function () {
new Vue({ el: '#myApp' })
}`, it's not possible to add script JS in footer backend plugin ,thought.

Comment: ok cool, `$(document).ready(function(event) {})` is just wrapper of `window.onload`, so will work as same as you did, nice work !